# Are there any programs that can create thumbnails for Vimeo videos?

Tags: video, software-rec, youtube, thumbnails, vimeo

I want to create thumbnails for Vimeo videos. Are there any programs that can do this quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimeo does this already for you, check the Developers-section within the Help-documentation on their website on a how-to to display them on your website. No need for extra software!